# API取得データのソート順について

Tags: microsoft-graph

Microsoft Graph API の次の API で、複数のメッセージを取得した場合に取得したメッセージはどのように並んでいるのか教えていただけないでしょうか。
ある項目をキーにしてソートされているのでしょうか。

チャネル メッセージを一覧表示する
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

チャット: getAllMessages
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/graph/api/chats-getallmessages?view=graph-rest-beta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

英語版のドキュメントに書かれているとおり、OData クエリパラメーターに対応していれば `$orderby` に対応しています。

- `GET /teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/messages` については "The other OData query parameters are not currently supported." と書かれているように、サポートされていません。
- `GET /users/{id | user-principal-name}/chats/getAllMessages` については "This operation supports date range parameters to customize the response" と書かれているように、サポートされています。

OData クエリパラメーターについてはこちら: https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/graph/query-parameters

> `$orderby` クエリ パラメーターを使用して、Microsof Graph から返される項目の並べ替え順序を指定します。 既定の順序は昇順です。